# JFileChooser Network Display

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I need to securely lock down a java desktop application on windows to only have access to the permitted drives.

How can I stop JFilechooser on a application from displaying and browsing the local network?

I have tried applying security policy but this doesn't seem to affect the display.

Comment: I don't think that's a problem you should solve at the application level.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`JFileChooser.setFileSystemView(FileSystemView)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setFileSystemView-javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView-).  The [`FileSystemView`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html)..

> ..is `JFileChooser's` gateway to the file system. Since the JDK1.1 File API doesn't allow access to such information as root partitions, file type information, or hidden file bits, this class is designed to intuit as much OS-specific file system information as possible.
>   Java Licensees may want to provide a different implementation of `FileSystemView` to better handle a given operating system.

The important part is to change the behavior of the [`isTraversable(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html#isTraversable-java.io.File-) method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i am able to control what is view-able with a custom FileSystemView. But now i get an exception when the user double clicks the file to open it. When i use the open button i do not get the error.

java.lang.InternalError: Unable to bind C:\Temp\alan.job to parent
        at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolder2$4.call(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.shell.Win32ShellFolderManager2$ComInvoker.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.awt.shell.ShellFolder.invoke(Unknown Source)

Comment: Seems like a separate question to me.  Post a new question thread.  For best help, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example) that demonstrate the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom SecurityManager. See [this article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187967&seqNum=3)